# Concatenate date and varchar

Tags: mysql, date, cast, concat

I am need to select the date stored in a column `transactionDate` datatype `date` and time stored in column `transactionTime` datatype `varchar` from a table `transactionTable` in mysql. My query is like

```
select concat( CAST( transactionDate as char), transactionTime) as transaction  
from transactionTable 
where id = 123
```

There are values in both the columns but the above returns me a null. How can I concat `date` and `varchar` columns?

Comment: If both values (in both columns) are not null, you'll get a result. If one of the two columns is null, the result of the `concat()` will be null. What do you want instead?

Comment: I would want it to return value of whichever isn't null in case one of them is null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CONCAT()` function returns `NULL` when one of the arguments is null. You could use `COALESCE()` to bypass the issue, converting the nulls to empty strings - or to any other constant value, for example `'00:00:00'` for the time part:

```
select concat( coalesce(cast(transactionDate as char), ''), 
               ' ', 
               coalesce(transactionTime, '00:00:00')
             ) as transaction  
from transactionTable 
where id = 123 ;
```

In fact, you don't really need an explicit `cast()`, the cast to `char` is implicit:

```
select concat( coalesce(transactionDate, ''), 
               ' ', 
               coalesce(transactionTime, '00:00:00')
             ) as transaction  
from transactionTable 
where id = 123 ;
```

Comment: In this query, you better have to use ISNULL function instead of COALESCE. It will be faster and will give the same result.

Comment: @Nico what are you talking about? Can you prove your claim that `ISNULL()` is faster than `COALESCE()`?

Comment: Not to mention that MySQL's `ISNULL()` returns either `1` or `0`. It is different than SQL-Server's `ISNULL()` (which I guess you confused it with).

Comment: Perhaps @Nico intended function `IFNULL()`. But the executions time  is pretty much the same.

Comment: @ypercube You're right! I was talking about IFNULL() not ISNULL().

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [**`CONCAT_WS`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function which (i) converts datatype automatically (ii) skips NULL values*:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', transactionDate, transactionTime) AS whatever
```

<sup>* If `transactionDate` is NULL then the result won't contain leading space. If `transactionTime` is NULL then result won't contain trailing space.</sup>